# FileNotFoundException after migrate project to AndroidX

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, migrate, androidx

I have got a problem.

I migrated my project to AndroidX using Android Studio ( Refractor --> Migrate to AndroidX )

The project migrated successfully, but when I am trying run app on my device, on **Build output** I have **FileNotFoundException** on ** app\build\instant_run_split_apk_resources\debug\instantRunSplitApkResourcesDebug\out\slice_1\resources_ap**

I tried **Clean project** and **Rebuild project** but it wasn't helping.

I looked for solution in internet, but I found nothing.

Please, help me !

Comment: Disable Instant run from File  -> Settings -> Instant Run & than check

Comment: It's working, thanks.

Comment: But I am using instant run to work with project and I want to turn on the instant run. How I can repair it ?